# OpenGL clear buffer when using a cubemap

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

I'm using nvidia nsight graphics to check out what happens when clearing a framebuffer using a cubemap.

I cannot figure out if the clearing affect all the six faces, or if I have to specify which face I'm rendering into before clear it.

I need to know how to clear correctly a cubemap in fact. Per face or by the framebuffer.

EDIT:

Here is the calling log :

```
Issues (324)    Event   Description CPU ms  GPU ms
563 "void glBindFramebuffer(GLenum target = GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLuint framebuffer = '4')"  0.02    -

Issues (324)    Event   Description CPU ms  GPU ms
565 "void glViewport(GLint x = 0, GLint y = 0, GLsizei width = 256, GLsizei height = 256)"  <0.01   -

Issues (324)    Event   Description CPU ms  GPU ms
566 "void glClearNamedFramebufferfv(GLuint framebuffer = '4', GLenum buffer = GL_DEPTH, GLint drawbuffer = 0, GLfloat* value = {1})"    0.03    <0.01

Issues (324)    Event   Description CPU ms  GPU ms
567 "void glNamedFramebufferTextureLayer(GLuint framebuffer = '4', GLenum attachment = GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GLuint texture = '59', GLint level = 0, GLint layer = 0)"   0.01    -

Issues (324)    Event   Description CPU ms  GPU ms
570 void glUseProgram(GLuint program = '616')   <0.01   -
```

Some drawings (I havn't reported the program and drawing log),
I saw primitives hitting the framebuffer in the nvidia software with no warning about nothing written, so I assume the framebuffer is valid.

Next face :

```
Issues (324)    Event   Description CPU ms  GPU ms
914 "void glNamedFramebufferTextureLayer(GLuint framebuffer = '4', GLenum attachment = GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GLuint texture = '59', GLint level = 0, GLint layer = 1)"   0.02    -
```

...
I don't clear anything and I start again to draw with a new matrix orientation until the 6 faces are rendered.

EDIT2, here is how I create the shadow cubemap:

```
glCreateTextures(
    GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,
    1, 
    &m_identifier
);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS);

glTextureStorage2D(
    m_identifier,
    1,
    GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F,
    256,
    256
);
```

Comment: How are you "using a cubemap" in this framebuffer? Did you attach the cubemap as a layered image, or only specific faces of the cubemap?

Comment: So here, I'm trying to render a depth cubemap, I loop the 6 faces by doing this : glNamedFramebufferTextureLayer(m_framebuffer.identifier(), GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, m_shadowTexture.identifier(), 0, static_cast< GLint >(face));

Comment: For a regular cubemap render (ie for reflexion), I use a cubemap as the color buffer, and a simple RBO for the depth. I clear the depth buffer before every face to reuse it, and leaving the color buffer alone until the end of render of the six faces. It's work fine. I got trouble with shadow cubemap rendering, so I want to be sure of the clearDepth() function.

Comment: "*Here is the calling log*" ... so, did you notice that you're clearing the framebuffer *before* attaching the image?

Comment: Yes, so that's my question, is glClearXXX() clear the whole framebuffer, or you must bind the layer before ?

Comment: And an other question comes to my mind, if I want to clear totally a framebuffer (for an other purpose) I need to loop trought all the 6 faces of a cubemap ?

Comment: "*is glClearXXX() clear the whole framebuffer, or you must bind the layer before ?*" ... what? If the image is not attached, then it's not part of "the whole framebuffer". I'm not sure what you're even asking here.

Comment: Ok, but the thing that bugs me a bit, it's when you build a framebuffer, you attached buffers on it. And I don't know what is really attached to, and what it implies on the framebuffer. In my structure, my vision is to create a framebuffer, then a texture, or a RBO, attach everything to the framebuffer, check if the framebuffer is valid, then when I want to use it, I bind the framebuffer, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: So I don't know If I'm clear enough (sorry, english is not my first langage), But when I'm building a framebuffer with a cubemap attached to it, my idea is, if I clear the framebuffer, it clears the whole cubemap. This is the point where I'm unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Framebuffers have images attached to them. Framebuffer operations affect the images that are currently attached to them.

Note that I said "images" and not *textures*". Textures *contain* images, but as far as a framebuffer is concerned, distinct images in the same texture have no relationship to one another. Framebuffer operations only affects the images that are attached to it at the time time.

If you attach a specific cubemap face to a framebuffer, then that face is the image attached to that attachment location in the FBO. Operations on the framebuffer will affect that image, but the framebuffer neither knows about nor cares about any other cubemap faces that may be in the texture. Framebuffers only deal with the currently attached images.

Furthermore, if you want to clear the framebuffer attached image you're about to use to render with, the image you want to clear must be attached to the FBO when you issue the clear call. Clearing, then attaching, makes no sense if you intend to clear the image that you're attaching.

If you want to clear an entire texture to a specific value (such as with all faces of a cubemap), you can [do that with `glClearTexImage`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Storage#Texture_clear).